# Close modal box on keypress

Tags: overlay, jquery

Trying to close a modal popup and remove the overlay as well when the user pushes the `ESC` key.

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) { 
    if (e.keyCode == 27) { 
       $('.create-folder').toggle();
    } 
});
```

The modal window is triggering closed, but the overlay remains, covering the page.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is just hiding the div. What you should do instead is to programatically close the modal using

```
$.modal.close();
```

or your

```
myModalObj.close();
```

Comment: This worked: 
    `$(document).keyup(function(e) { 
         if (e.keyCode == 27) { 
           $('.create-folder').hide();
           $('.modal-overlay').hide();
        }   
    });

Answer (score 0):

If your using a Jquery dialog window just do:

```
$( ".create-folder" ).dialog( "close" );
```

just like you already probably called

```
$('.create-folder').dialog("open");
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) { 
    if (e.keyCode == 27) { 
       //hides modal overlay background when escape key pressed
       $('.modal-overlay').hide();
       //hides all modal boxes when escape key pressed
       $('.modal').hide();
    } 
});
```